# Detecting location of music note dots in a sheet music image

Tags: image-processing

I want to start a project that uses a very basic form of optical music recognition.

**For those who understand sheet music:** Unlike other OMR projects, the only information which needs to be extracted is the order and pitch values of each note in a bar. Quarter notes, half notes and whole notes need to be distinguished. Shorter notes can acceptably be interpreted as quarter notes. Dots on notes can be ignored. Dynamics markings are not important

**For everyone:** Strictly speaking I need to find the locations of each of the following...

[image]

... in a sample image like this...
[image]

I have no experience in image processing so a basic, conceptual explanation of what technique or set of techniques are used to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be more suitable to dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

Extract the line locations using Hough transform. (You get the angle as well).  Crop each group of lines (5 lines), and process individually.

For each group of lines, you know the angle of the lines, so you can get the locations of the vertical small lines that separate the bars. Search again in Hough space, but with specific angle. (The original + 90). Crop each bar and process individually.

For each bar, use template matching on the possible notes (Quarter, Half,etc..)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey, I'll look into these. Hadn't thought to look for the lines before the dots.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to your work and trust me it is a complete mess.

Howeverr, for the pitch for each note you extract the head from the rest and calculate the baricentre and compare its position to the position of lines calculated with Hough transform as already said (assuming that the lines are already straight: if not i think you can use the Fourier Transform).

For the duration you need a classification algorithm.